# Why does the same curl command output different things in windows and linux?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, curl, terminal

Why does the same `curl -o file https://www.link.com/` command output different things?

For example if i run the command `curl -o source.txt https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIx6FwnpuyNW9RxmWaGzKumLu-gUPy-q4` with a YouTube playlist link.

Linux output everything including all of the entries (titles, thumbnails, links, etc.).

Windows on the other hand will only output the layout of the page, skipping everything playlist stuff.

What am I missing here? Why is this the case and is there a different Windows command that achieves the same thing?

Comment: Well, are you using the same command in PowerShell on Linux and vise-versa?

Comment: Yeah I am using the same command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Curl.exe` **is present** in box on Windows machines with Windows 10 1803 or higher (which means since roughly March of 2018) and similar server releases.

However, `curl` (with no .exe) has a somewhat weird history and some shortcuts are left behind built into PowerShell, and I think that is what's causing you some grief.

What do I mean?

Give this a try on your machine.

```
get-command curl

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

You might be surprised to find that `curl` in PowerShell is an alias for a built-in cmdlet called `Invoke-WebRequest`.  This acts somewhat similarly to `curl` in Linux or the `curl.exe` program, but is really quite different.

However, try that again with the full executable name.

```
 gcm curl.exe

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     curl.exe                                           7.55.1.0   C:\WINDOWS\system32\curl.exe
```

This means that running `curl` and running `curl.exe` are two different things!

If you try your command like so, it should be similar to what you find in Linux.

```
curl.exe -o source.txt https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIx6FwnpuyNW9RxmWaGzKumLu-gUPy-q4
```

Comment: `curl.exe` _ships with_ recent versions of Windows 10 and Windows Sever 2019 and is available via `$env:PATH`. In _Windows PowerShell_ (but no longer in _PowerShell (Core) 7+_), the built-in `curl` alias indeed preempts `curl.exe` _if invoked as `curl`_ - a simple workaround  is to call `curl.exe`, i.e. to include the filename extension. That said, the specific, dowload-to-file command in the question behaves the same with both `curl.exe` and `Invoke-WebRequest` in principle, though with the given URL there will be variations due to embedded identifiers generated anew for each download op.

Comment: Wow, that's crazy, I was still downloading curl on all of my Windows machines like a caveman.  Here's the announcement for curl shipping with windows.  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/ba-p/382409

Comment: You are right I would seem that `curl` and `curl.exe` behave differently. Thanks!