# different result on windows and Linux for curl while downloading file having zero size

Tags: windows, curl, opensuse

Downloading a null file (file size - 0 bytes) on windows (windows 10) results in downloading the file (file size -0 bytes).

```
curl -v --max-filesize 30001 -o C:\Users\erik\Documents\temp\t1\abc.zip file://C:\Users\erik\Documents\test\t1.zip

curl --version
curl 7.83.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.83.1 Schannel
Release-Date: 2022-05-13
```

But the same command on Linux does not download the file.

```
curl -v --max-filesize 30001 -o /home/erik/temp/test/te.zip file:///home/erik/FileSizeZeroTest/t1.zip

curl --version
curl 7.37.0 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.37.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2j zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
```

After reading [Why does the same curl command output different things in windows and linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69261782/why-does-the-same-curl-command-output-different-things-in-windows-and-linux),
It seems that the curl on windows and other operating systems behaves differently.

Please comment/help if I am getting it correct.

Comment: The curl _program_ on Windows is not significantly different from other systems, although it may (yours does) use Schannel for SSL/TLS which results in minor differences such as in accepting some certs, but you already get such variation between Unixes where depending on builder curl can use OpenSSL GnuTLS or NSS, plus SecureTransport on MacOS[X], all of which have minor differences. Your link is about  the command 'curl' IN POWERSHELL which doesn't run the curl program at all, it runs a PowerShell _cmdlet_ 'invoke-webrequest' instead and that IS quite different. ...

Comment: ... However, this does appear to be a change in the curl program; my Ubuntu 16.04 has 7.47.0 and it _does_ 'download' an empty file, while a very old archive CentOS 6 has 7.19.7 which doesn't (it shows the progress display, but doesn't create the file; I assume that's what you meant). (Of course file: isn't really downloading because it's local, but curl tries to make all URLs similar.) But this is isn't programming or development.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085, Yes I mean that only - it shows the progress display, but doesn't create the file.
Updating the curl version to the latest might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest version 7.85.0 solved the issue.